# Redis Pub/Sub in Rust: Message Not Received

Tags: rust, redis, connection, rust-cargo

I am attempting to send data through channel creation using Redis pub/sub. The issue is that the message is not being received, even if it is published. What am I doing wrong in this? And how can I correct it? I am a novice in Rust.

```
use redis::{Client, Commands, RedisError};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<(), RedisError> {
    // Connect to Redis
    let client = redis::Client::open("redis://127.0.0.1/")?;
    let mut con = client.get_connection()?;
    println!("Successfully connected to Redis!");
    let channel = "mychannel";
    let message = "hello";
    con.publish(channel, message)?;
    let mut pubsub = con.as_pubsub();

    pubsub.subscribe("mychannel")?;
    println!("subscribed to mychannel");

    loop {
        println!("waiting for message");
        let msg = pubsub.get_message()?;
        let payload: String = msg.get_payload()?;
        println!("Received data on mychannel: {}", payload);
    
        println!("got message");
    }


}
```

Comment: Where are you sending messages from? Are you expecting to receive the `"hello"` message that you sent before subscribing?

Comment: @PitaJ basically i have to create pubsub with Redis and listening to Redis. In above example , ya i am sending hello as of now to keep it simple for past. aslo expecting that to recieve it too

Comment: I think you will need to publish after subscribing, which means you will need to open a separate connection etc. Or you can try publishing from the redis CLI just to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you need to `subscribe` before you publish message.
Redis Pub/Sub it simply delivers the message to all current subscribers at the time of publishing.
Try that:

```rust
let mut pubsub = con.as_pubsub();
pubsub.subscribe("mychannel")?;
println!("subscribed to mychannel");

// now you can publish message
con.publish(channel, message)?;
```